# Accurate cross-platform sound manipulation

Tags: c++, cross-platform, audio, wav

How can I play and pause a wave file in C++ and get the length and duration in which its been played in milliseconds. It should preferably be cross-platform but not Qt as QSound is to simple and phonon require DirectX and doesn't work with mingw. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a low-level library like [libAO](http://www.xiph.org/ao/). You control how much gets played, and so to "pause," you would simply stop calling `ao_play()` and count the number of samples you've sent.

Simple audio playback is not really such a complex task that it requires complex APIs.

Comment: +1 This library is extremely simple to use and straight forward. Its a shame its not object orientated. Also, requires custom mixer if you want to play multiple sounds.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.portaudio.com/. Also, SFML has an audio module: http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php. Also, commercial (but free to use, depending on the project) alternatives like http://www.fmod.org/ and [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) (Win, Mac) exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the source code for [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) you might find some helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is always [jack](http://jackaudio.org). Its pretty easy to use and has good documentation, plus its intended as a low latency cross platform I/O with integrated tools to handle network sound processing. Rather nice piece of software for what it sounds like you are trying to do.